# Sharing objects between tags Riot.js

Tags: tags, observable, riot.js

If an object is created in tag-a how can it be accessed in tag-b?

tag-a.tag

```
<tag-a>

<script>
 const o = {data: () => {return "something" }}
</script>

</tag-a>
```

tag-b.tag

```
<tag-b>

<script>
 // access object o created in tag-a
</script>

</tag-b>
```

I've tried using a mixin but I think this would need to be registered in a parent tag?

Answer (score 1):

If they share a parent you can do something like this, but is not recommended as the tags will get coupled.

```
<parent>
  <tag-a></tag-a>
  <tag-b></tag-b>
</parent>

<tag-a>
  <script>
    this.o = 'Hi bro'
  </script>  
</tag-a>

<tag-b>
  <span>{this.parent.tags.tag-a.o}</span>
</tag-b>
```

More info about simple tag communication:
http://vitomd.com/blog/coding/tag-communication-in-riot-js-part-1/

A better approach will be to communicate using the observable pattern.

First you create a store.js

```
//Store.js
var Store = function(){
  riot.observable(this)
}
```

Then in the index.html before mounting the tags you add the store to the global riot variable, so it will be accessible from any tag

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  riot.store = new Store()
  riot.mount('* ')
</script>
```

Then in tag-a you can trigger to send the info

```
send_info() {
  riot.store.trigger('send_to_b', 'Hello')    
}
```

And in tag-b receive the message

```
riot.store.on('send_to_b', function(greeting) {
  self.hi = greeting
})
```

More info: http://vitomd.com/blog/coding/tag-communication-in-riot-js-part-2/